# In which direction due to a polarizing grid the photon's electric field is oriented?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, polarization

After a photon passes the slit, is it's electric field oriented perpendicular or parallel to the slit and why this is so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wire grid polarisers allow radiation to pass that has it's electric field polarised perpendicularly to the direction of the wires.

The explanation is that the component of the light polarised parallel to the wires sees the grid as if it were a solid conductor and therefore most of it is reflected and the rest absorbed in the first couple of skin depths.

In order to act like this the grid spacing must be smaller than the wavelength. I guess this is why microwave ovens have a mesh on the door with wires in two perpendicular directions.

Comment: Your answer corresponds with [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44863/why-does-the-electric-field-dominate-in-light?rq=1) one from @Anna v. Nice.

Comment: One additional question arise: How the direction of the electric field was measured after photon pass the grid?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Just see which way the field accelerates electrons - i.e. with an aerial.

Comment: If you switch to different frequences you want to discover, do you change the distance of the grid from the aerial for best results?